# Run Nunit precompiled test

Tags: c#, nunit

I have a project containing Nunit test.

I have the code project with all interfaces implemented but no code. All function throws exceptions.

My gol is to give someone else the implemntation of the code. His job will be done when the all tests will be green.

What I'd like is to give him the test cases (nunit) to be able to run them.ì, but not the inner code of the tests.

I had 2 ideas :

- password lock the nunit project.
- precompile the nunit project

I couldn't figure out how to implement neither one of the two.

Anyone has an advice on how to rach my goal?

Thanks

Comment: You may be able to do that with a published interface.  Generally speaking, in an Agile world, testers should work side-by-side with developers (of course it is quite possible that developers are also the testers) so as to promote increased team-work; communication and understanding.  It's possible that your approach may cause `unnecessary barriers` even within different divisions of Test?   What do you think?  I wish you and your team well.  (plus unless your obfuscate, your colleague could load it into _Reflector_)

Comment: Good point but my case is a little bit different (I forgot to tell this). This case I submit is not a setup for co-workers. I am actually a teacher and this setup is meant for my students. That is why I don't want them to see tests code. They'll probably just write a lot of "if" and "return" with all cases in tests

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps an easy way is to put the unit tests on a *continuous integration* (CI) server (e.g. Jenkins; TeamCity) and only on the CI server that during a check-in of code runs the unit tests over his code.  You could if you like, put the source code for the nUnit tests elsewhere in SCM or deny access to it if there is a security requirement which you hinted at.  That may be suitable perhaps?

> His job will be done when the all tests will be green

That can be performed by opening the CI tool of your choice and examining the dashboard for "green lights".

That way the developer never actually sees the tests, code or otherwise.  They can just focus on developing their code.  This can be beneficial for those teams where there are distinct developers and testers.

No need to password-lock nor pre-compile the library, because the developer never makes use of it, only the CI server which you can deploy to by a suitable means.

Hope this is suitable.

**EDIT:**  Upon learning this is actually a **class-room** setting, setting up a *CI* server may be slight over-kill.  Perhaps just compile the nUnit tests into a **.dll** and hand-out to your students to run with the `nUnit GUI`?

Comment: This is probably too late to be useful in this situation but Jenkins can be installed in about an hour (it includes an embedded web server so the Windows install is a fairly simple all-in-one package).  Writing the Jenkins jobs to do what you want requires some learning but in an educational context this job could be passed to a senior student as useful skill development.

Comment: Jenkins also has multiple ways to publish the results of a test so the students wouldn't need to see Jenkins: they'd submit their source to a source repository or predefined shared folder and several minutes later would be emailed a result.  It's a bit of setup (perhaps a day or two) but could be re-used as a standard assignment completion mechanism.